# How to iterate a functional component & then set state by changing record in react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Hi I have created a Parent component & then iterating a child component over a JSON array & then I am trying to do some change in child component. It's not working properly.

My parent Component code is -

```
import React from 'react';
const jsonData = require('sampleData.json');
export const ParentComponent = (): React.ReactElement => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {jsonData.myList.map(
                (listData: ListInterface): React.ReactElement => {
                    return (
                        <ChildComponent
                            key={listData.id}
                            {...listData}
                        />
                    );
                }
            )}
                </React.Fragment>
        
    );
};
```

Child Component code is -

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Grid } from '@material-ui/core';

export const ChildComponent = (props: ListInterface): React.ReactElement => {
    const { listType , listArrayData , listText} = props;
    const onChange = (selectedValue: string | number, selectType: string) => {
        console.log("selectedValue", selectedValue, "selectType : ", selectType);
    };

    const MyLisData = (listType: string) => {
        switch (listType) {
            case 'FIRST':
                return (
                    <Grid container item>
                        <label>{listText}</label>
                        <Input
                            value={listArrayData[0].value}
                            onChange={(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
                                onChange(event.target.value, 'FIRST');
                            }}
                            id={'FirstListData'}
                        />
                    </Grid>
                );

            case 'SECOND':
                return (
                    <Grid container item>
                        <label>{listText}</label>
                        <TextBox
                            value={listArrayData[0].value}
                            onChange={(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
                                onChange(event.target.value, 'SECOND');
                            }}
                            id={'SecondListData'}
                        />
                    </Grid>
                );
            default:
                return null;
        }
    };
    return (
        <Grid container>
            {MyLisData(listType)}
        </Grid>
    );
};
```

When I am trying to change some data in Text & Input inside child component then It's not working properly as component is rendering every time. I want all the changed value on Parent Component. Everytime I change the record inside Child component, I should get changed data in Parent component. Can anyone help me in changing record & then set state as I am stuck in it ?

Answer (score 0):

Learn about controlled and uncontrolled components in react. You can either introduce state to parent component and use your json as default value for its state (then you need to use parent setState on input change), or change input prop value to defaultValue but then you dont have state on react.
Now what you are doing, by passing value to input, is telling react you will always provide proper value by this props. Your onChange function its not changing this prop, as it is only console log.